# How to import an account to Keyring which was exported from the polkadot{.js] browser extension?

Tags: polkadot-js, keyring

I have installed the polkadot{.js} browser extension and exported an account to a json-file.
I want to have that account available on a server where I have installed the @polkadot/keyring  library.

Is there a way I can use the information in the exported json file to Add an account to the keyring ? so that the imported account uses the same private/public key ?

The exported JSON looks like this:

`{"encoded":"e3/31ir...XXX","encoding":{"content":["pkcs8","sr25519"],"type":["scrypt","xsalsa20-poly1305"],"version":"3" }, "address":"5GTvRV9XXXX", "meta":{"genesisHash":"", "name":"Account3", "whenCreated":1676907491720}}`

Want to add Account to Keyring from exported polkadot{.js} account.

Comment: https://github.com/polkadot-js/build-bundle/blob/fef7a3b2e89e285b3de0e4b9c00c9f94350af3bb/bundle-polkadot-ui-keyring.js#L2640

Comment: @niklas thanks. I will try that out. Also I found an easy way to import an account to polkadot/keyring is to just use the seed phrase like this:                                        
const PHRASE_ACCOUNT = 'XXX XXXX XXXX';
const newPair = keyring.createFromUri(PHRASE_ACCOUNT);